# linux search expression in [abc]

Tags: grep

I have several lines like:

**[abc] yy abc yy**

**[abc] yy fff yy**

**abc yy ddd yy**

And I want to search and get only the lines with expression **[abc]** -between the square brackets- and not the ones with **abc** only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since brackets have special meaning in grep's regular expression syntax, you either need to escape them

```
grep '\[abc\]' file
```

or specify plain string matching using `-F` or `--fixed-strings`

```
grep -F '[abc]' file
```

See `man grep`

```
-F, --fixed-strings
       Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular
       expressions), separated by newlines,  any  of  which  is  to  be
       matched.
```

Answer (score 0):

use grep:

```
grep '\[abc\]' filename
```

Comment: Google "Useless use of cat". `grep '\[abc\]' file`

Answer (score 0):

If the text to be searched is stored in a file called FILE, change directories using `cd` to the directory that contains FILE and run this command:

```
grep \\[abc\\] < FILE
```

This command has minimalist style because it does not require any extra quote characters and does not have any useless uses of `cat`.

- Instead of `cat` it uses a single left angle bracket `<`.
- Instead of using quote characters, the left and right square brackets are both escaped in order to be interpreted literally as square bracket characters.